# Dropdownlist SelectIndexChanged Not firing C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback

I don't get on well with post back/DDL's.. yes I have used autopostback = true!

Below, I am trying to get the selected index changed... to fire on budgetDDL1 however, whatever I try it doesn't!

I'm binding data from a DB to the ddl...

I've tried binding/adding the ddl to the table inside/outside the post backs and enabling/disabling the view states etc.. none of this works.. there must be an easy answer?!

In what order do I need to create/bind the dropdowns for the index changed method to fire an explanation would be useful too!

```html
   DropDownList budgetDDL1 = new DropDownList();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string QueryString = "SELECT [BudgetCode], [Department], CONCAT([BudgetCode],' - ', [Department]) AS 'textvalue' FROM [tblBudget]";
                using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryString, myConnection))
                    {
                        myConnection.Open();
                        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt.Load(dr);
                        budgetDDL1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        budgetDDL1.DataSource = dt;
                        budgetDDL1.DataTextField = "textvalue";
                        budgetDDL1.DataValueField = "BudgetCode";
 budgetDDL1.AutoPostBack = true;
            budgetDDL1.SelectedIndexChanged += budgetDDL1_SelectedIndexChanged;
            budgetDDL1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
       
            table1.Controls.Add(budgetDDL1);
        }
```

```
 protected void budgetDDL1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { *I have a breakpoint here which doesn't fire*
        string msg = budgetDDL1.SelectedItem.Text;
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(sender as System.Web.UI.Control, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + msg + "')", true);
    }
```

```html
view:
    <body>
    <form  runat="server">
    <table>
      <tr>    
       <td id="table1" runat="server">
       </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Probably your control is not getting added ro control hierarchy on page postback. Please share your view code.

Comment: My view code as in the aspx? It's just a long table within a form tag.. I am adding the DDL into a table cell(td) with the id of table1

Comment: Added the view.. it has more rows etc, but just showed the basic structure

Answer (score 0):

Place auto post back code out side of the !`IsPostback`

```
    DropDownList budgetDDL1 = new DropDownList();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string QueryString = "SELECT [BudgetCode], [Department], CONCAT([BudgetCode],' - ', [Department]) AS 'textvalue' FROM [tblBudget]";
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryString, myConnection))
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    budgetDDL1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    budgetDDL1.DataSource = dt;
                    budgetDDL1.DataTextField = "textvalue";
                    budgetDDL1.DataValueField = "BudgetCode";

                }
            }
        }
        budgetDDL1.AutoPostBack = true;
        budgetDDL1.SelectedIndexChanged += budgetDDL1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        budgetDDL1.DataBind();

        table1.Controls.Add(budgetDDL1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic controls should be added on *Init*. After **OnLoad** finishes executing ASP.NET starts processing control's events and values. You can read/write their properties on or after Load.

Suggest you to check the place where you have created **DropDownList**.

**Answer:** because you have created DropDownList after the events have been processed.

Have a look here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this i'll have a read! For some reason I can see my breakpoint DDL indexchange fires when I do a click a button(different postback) so it's being held up somewhere.